# DirectoryInfo accessing a virtual folder

Tags: c#, virtual-directory, fileinfo, directoryinfo

I'm trying to use DirectoryList on a virtual directory, to build up a list of files.  However I get the error;

> URI not supported

Is there an alternative to this that supports URLs?  Here's my code so far.....

```
DirectoryInfo directoryinfo = new DirectoryInfo("http://localhost:1080/mydatafolder");
IEnumerable<FileInfo> fileList = directoryinfo.GetFiles();
```

As double check, I've made sure the directory browsing has been turned on, and I can surf to it using Opera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get a list of files from a remote HTTP server you could use the [HttpWebRequest class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) to **post a directory listing request and parse the contents of the HTML index page** returned by IIS.

Here's a start:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://servername/directoryname/");
var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    string body = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

**Related resources:**

- [Downloading Multiple Files over HTTP Connection](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/DownloadDemo.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, quite illuminating.  Appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

DirectoryInfo is for the filesystem only, you should use DirectoryEntry to get IIS information.

Have a look at this article to see all kinds of ways to get & modify IIS metadata using c#:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/iismanager.aspx